# Apple watch takes a lot of time to respond from parent application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

When the app is installed in the iPhone device and without even running the app even once, i m running the watch app. And i am calling an API to get data from the server.

I am using this

```
[[self class] openParentApplication:nil reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
}
```

And in the AppDelegate.m of the app

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply {
}
```

Now I have not started my app even once. So the API is not giving any response to the Watch Extension so that i can update. But when i start the app before starting the watch app. Everything works fine.

Is there a way to at least get a response? An error or even a timeout will do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .@trycatchfinally LOL your username.

Comment: @"LOL your username" LOL your comment

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it seems like the first call never seems to "succeed" when the app has not been loaded. I have no idea why but I could never get that call to reply.

I've gotten around this by just throwing an empty call (I use the apt method name of "dummy") to the parent app to "wake it up" and just reply(null) before I send the real, data intensive call. Its not ideal, but it got me passed that hurdle.